# Offline update then upload files to server

Tags: updates, manual-updates

What's the best way to update Craft offline and then upload the files to the server? Reason I'm asking is because my updates often fail because of too low PHP memory and I don't have control over the server to update the minimum value.

This is my process right now:

- Backup everything (files + db)
- Updating the composer.json file manually to the versions that are shown in the admin panel.
- Run 'composer update --no-dev'
- Upload vendor directory, composer.json and composer.lock to the server
- Refresh admin panel and finish update.

Is this the way to go or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not able to increase your server's `memory_limit` and/or `max_execution_time` settings, then your current process is a way to "manually" update Craft 3.

Alternatively, if your server has Composer [installed](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx) from the command line and you have SSH access, you can perform the composer update locally, then upload your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files, then execute `composer install` from your project's root.

That method should use less memory than updating from the Control Panel.